# How can I rewrite 'with whom' in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Here's a sentence in my essay:

> These institutions will allow me to work with peers with whom we have similar academic interests.

I think to make it grammatically correct, I may want to use 'with whom', but it sounds a bit weird to include two 'with's so close in this sentence. I am thinking about rewriting the sentence as

> These institutions will allow me to work with peers whom we have similar academic interests with.

Is the grammar correct here? Is there a better way I can phrase this sentence? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: These institutions will allow me to work with peers who share similar academic interests. (Your example doesn't specify the referent of 'we', so neither can I.)

Comment: Just *...peers **having** similar academic interests*. The question *Similar to **who**?* is ambiguously addressed in the original *(Similar to **me**? To **us**?)*, so I think it's better to simply drop that part and let the reader make whatever seems the logical assumption. (If he cares about that level of detail, which I doubt! :)

Comment: Both **peers whose academic interests we share** or **peers who share our academic interests** would be far easier to understand.  If you want to emphasize *similar not same* then try **peers whose academic interests overlap ours**.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, "whom" is used as a relative pronoun (a category of pronoun) and is functioning as the object of the preposition "with". As explained in [The Farlex Grammar Book](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Relative-Pronouns.htm), positioning prepositions in front of relative pronouns often sounds overly formal, especially when it comes to the relative pronoun "whom". As a result, it is generally acceptable for a preposition to come after a relative clause instead of before a relative pronoun. Alternatively, you can omit it entirely. Therefore, your sentence can read:

> These institutions will allow me to work with peers with whom we have similar academic interests. (very formal)

or

> These institutions will allow me to work with peers whom we have similar academic interests with (less formal)

or

> These institutions will allow me to work with peers we have similar academic interests with (most casual)

Hopefully my explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful :)